# Google Sheets API Chart - change a given datapoint fillcolor

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

In Google Sheets API, when using a chart shape, how can I colour a given datapoint a custom RGB? In the image below I have changed the color of 3 random datapoints. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the color and use a custom RGB color. If you already have the chart created, all you need to do is to use the `batchUpdate` method, and when creating the request include `updateChartSpecRequest`, then you'll need to select the type of chart that you are updating. In your case, based on the screenshot it would be `basicChart`, then from the chart, you want to update the `series` since those are the ones that generate the columns, and you can modify the `color` parameter there according to the official documentation.

Depending on what you want to end up doing, the structure of the request may end up being similar to this:

#### Request:

```
'request' : [
    {
        "updateChartSpec": {
            "chartId": integer,
            "spec": {
                "basicChart": {
                    "series": [
                        {
                            "color": {
                                {
                                    "red": number,
                                    "green": number,
                                    "blue": number,
                                    "alpha": number
                                }
                            },
                        }
                    ]
                },
            }
        },
    }
]
```

##### Note:

If you want to do it upon creation, instead of using `updateChartSpec` you would want to use `addChart`.

References:

- [updateChartSpecRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatechartspecrequest)
- [Color](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#color)
- [BasicChartSeries](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#basicchartseries)
- [BasicChartSpec](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/charts#basicchartspec)
- [addChart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addchartrequest)

Comment: Thanks for the answer though I'm not sure if it answers my question. What would the JSON structure look like if I wanted to paint 1 specific datapoint within a series? For example, how do I change the 3rd series' first data point to green?

Comment: You can use the `spreadsheets.get` method listed [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) in order to get the exact structure of your chart inside the spreadsheet, then use the `batchUpdate` using the structure I mentioned as a sample in order to update the colors as desired @Boosted_d16 just be aware that you will get the full structure of your sheet file, meaning that if you have any additional data it will appear there too. If you want to only get the chart structure you can copy the chart into a separate file and get the structure from that file.